# C# from Ruby Wilson score

Tags: c#, ruby

Can anyone help me convert this to C#. It's literally hurting my brain.

http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html

[image: Wilsons Score]

```
require 'statistics2'

def ci_lower_bound(pos, n, power)
    if n == 0
        return 0
    end
    z = Statistics2.pnormaldist(1-power/2)
    phat = 1.0*pos/n
    (phat + z*z/(2*n) - z * Math.sqrt((phat*(1-phat)+z*z/(4*n))/n))/(1+z*z/n)
end
```

What does this mean?

```
Statistics2.pnormaldist(1-power/2)
```

Comment: That hurts my brain just to look at.  Have you tried http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/fb3a8714-e458-4b7d-b669-1bd610258081/?  Also, here is normal distribution in C# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.statisticformula.normaldistribution(VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anyone is interested...

doing more googling of pnormaldist led me to this stackoverflow artice: [Objective-C implementation of the Wilson Score Interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687497/objective-c-implementation-of-the-wilson-score-interval)

I converted this objective-c to C# mannually and it's completely untested

```
public class WilsonScore
{
    private static double pnormaldist(double qn)
    {
        double[] b = { 1.570796288, 0.03706987906, -0.8364353589e-3, -0.2250947176e-3, 
                         0.6841218299e-5, 0.5824238515e-5, -0.104527497e-5, 
                         0.8360937017e-7, -0.3231081277e-8, 0.3657763036e-10, 
                         0.6936233982e-12 };

        if (qn < 0.0 || 1.0 < qn)
            return 0.0;

        if (qn == 0.5)
            return 0.0;

        double w1 = qn;
        if (qn > 0.5)
            w1 = 1.0 - w1;
        double w3 = -Math.Log(4.0 * w1 * (1.0 - w1));
        w1 = b[0];
        int i = 1;
        for (; i < 11; i++)
            w1 += b[i] * Math.Pow(w3, i);

        if (qn > 0.5)
            return Math.Sqrt(w1 * w3);
        return -Math.Sqrt(w1 * w3);
    }

    public static double ci_lower_bound(int pos, int n, double power)
    {
        if (n == 0)
            return 0.0;
        double z = pnormaldist(1 - power / 2);
        double phat = 1.0 * pos / n;
        return (phat + z * z / (2 * n) - z * Math.Sqrt((phat * (1 - phat) + z * z / (4 * n)) / n)) / (1 + z * z / n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you answer yourself with a "completely untested" code and check it as the correct answer? Does anyone know if this is returning the correct results? I don't know the maths to test it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to google for it?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/fb3a8714-e458-4b7d-b669-1bd610258081/

First response, direct from MSDN.

Comment: Your google skills are epic. However that link is still pretty convoluted to me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution, almost identical to the accepted one but mine is tested. I haven't copied the solution but the strategy: Inspired by [How Not To Sort By Average Rating](http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html) I have coded the Wilson interval and the inverse cumulative density function checking multiple ruby and python repositories.

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Computes confidence interval.
    /// </summary>
    public static class ConfidenceInterval
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Calculates the Wilson Score Interval based on the total positives and the class positives (like positive votes).
        ///     <see href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval" />
        ///     <see href="http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html" />
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="positives">Number of class positives.</param>
        /// <param name="total">Total number of positives.</param>
        /// <param name="confidence">
        ///     Confidence level or coverage. Quantifies the level of confidence that the deterministic
        ///     parameter is captured by the interval. Defaults to 0.95 (95%).
        /// </param>
        public static Interval WilsonScoreInterval(long positives, long total, double confidence = 0.95)
        {
            if (total <= 0 || total < positives)
            {
                return new Interval();
            }

            positives = positives < 0 ? 0 : positives;

            var quantile = 1 - (1 - confidence) / 2;
            var z = PNormalDist(quantile);
            double n = total;
            var pHat = positives / n;
            var z2 = z * z;

            var hat = pHat + z2 / (2 * n);
            var sqrt = z * Math.Sqrt((pHat * (1 - pHat) + z2 / (4 * n)) / n);
            var divisor = 1 + z2 / n;

            return new Interval {
                LowerBound = (hat - sqrt) / divisor,
                UpperBound = (hat + sqrt) / divisor
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Inverse of normal-distribution. P( (-infinity, x] ) = quantile -> x
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="quantile">Probability quantile. <see href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile" /></param>
        /// <returns>The inverse Cumulative Density Function or P-value of the corresponding integral.</returns>
        private static double PNormalDist(double quantile)
        {
            if (quantile < 0.0 || 1.0 < quantile || Math.Abs(quantile - 0.5) < 0.0000001)
            {
                return 0.0;
            }

            double[] pNormTable = {
                1.570796288,
                0.03706987906,
                -0.8364353589e-3,
                -0.2250947176e-3,
                0.6841218299e-5,
                0.5824238515e-5,
                -0.104527497e-5,
                0.8360937017e-7,
                -0.3231081277e-8,
                0.3657763036e-10,
                0.6936233982e-12
            };

            var temp1 = quantile > 0.5 ? 1.0 - quantile : quantile;

            var temp2 = -Math.Log(4.0 * temp1 * (1.0 - temp1));

            var temp3 = pNormTable[0];

            for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++)
            {
                temp3 += pNormTable[i] * Math.Pow(temp2, i);
            }

            return quantile > 0.5 ? Math.Sqrt(temp3 * temp2) : -Math.Sqrt(temp3 * temp2);
        }

        public class Interval
        {
            /// <summary>
            ///     Lower bound.
            /// </summary>
            public double LowerBound { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            ///     Upper bound.
            /// </summary>
            public double UpperBound { get; set; } = 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the same library to Ruby:

https://github.com/abscondment/statistics2/blob/master/lib/statistics2.rb
https://github.com/abscondment/statistics2/blob/master/lib/statistics2/version.rb